# Animation Nodes: Propogate a vector path along either X "OR" Y axis randomly without overlap

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to make a maze like vector path which only has 90 degree turns and no intersection

Using a parameter loop with "Reassign" mode + a random boolean controlling which axis gets a value added i've managed to make a random 90degree only vector path as seen in the screenshot.

Now the only problem is sometimes there is overlap and i'm not sure what method to use to prevent this

Was wondering if there is anyway to do a maze pattern like the old windows xp Pipe screensaver but just propagating along going on the floor plane
[image: concept]
Yellow= possible paths,Green= path taken

[image: main]
[image: node tree]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do: the tree makes a spline. But a spline has no ramifications. So?

Comment: @lemon spline used just for visualization...will be replaced by Road/tunnel mesh or for randomized maze generation with no intersections

Comment: You could define an x by y "floor grid" of possible vector locations for the path, then each iteration as the path progresses, flag each vertex as 'used' so that later it will be filtered out as a possible destination for the growing path.  You can use reassign to filter out used grid points at each step.

Comment: @zippy interesting solution. So X or Y will move in random rounded integer increments. and at each increment loop will have to compare the location to grid flag list and see if it has a true  or false for that location then proceed if false or switch axis if true .Logic is correct ?

Comment: @Prime007 yes, that's the general idea.  Like a game of snake.  Sort of a random walk, but with limitations.  It's likely that this will result in lots of dead ends, though, which might mean you have to make other arrangements.
If you want to guarantee your maze is solvable, you might need to determine the correct path first, then backfill using this sort of random meandering paths.